# Spring Batch write certain records to different files restart issue

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job that reads from a file and writes to two flat files (in different formats). It uses a CompositeWriter that has two delegates which are custom classes that extend FlatFileItemWriter. Each writer writes only certain records. For example, with 14 input records the GoodFileWriter will write 12 records and the SkipFileWriter will write only two. This works just fine. However, if the job fails in the middle and I restart it the good file is missing records. It seems like Spring Batch is only maintaining the file size / record count of one of the files. I will be happy to provide examples if need be.

I have to believe this is just due to my incompetence with Spring Batch so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without see your code I only guess SB doesn't save state for all two streams,but only for one.
You have to manually register all the streams you are writing to using the 'streams' element as described in [official doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#registeringItemStreams)
Just an advice: you wrote you have extended `FlatFileItemWriter` for you custom writer. With SB the best solution - is possible - is to use delegation and not extension. Check your code if you can rewrite it using `ItemStream`, `ItemWriter` or use the composite superclass [`AbstractItemStreamItemWriter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemStreamItemWriter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since registering the streams, extending the FlatFileItemWriter and implementing ItemStream and ItemWriter with a file writer delegate did not work, here is the answer I came up with. I set the name property of the writers uniquely; either in the constructor of the Java class or the XML definition of the writer. This method worked either extending the FlatFileItemWriter or using a custom writer that implements ItemStream and ItemWriter with a FlatFileItemWriter delegate. The name property is coming from the ItemStreamSupport abstract class.

Spring Batch stores the amount written to a file in the execution context under the name.written key. The default name of the FlatFileItemWriter is FlatFileItemWriter. Since I had two FlatFileItemWriters there was only one item written to the execution context. Since one file had more written to it than the other corruption occurred on a restart. Uniquely naming the writers resolved this. If there is a more appropriate way to handle this I would appreciate hearing it.

Thanks to Luca Basso Ricci for pointing me in this direction with his comment regarding Spring Batch not saving state for the two streams.